# Apache mod_proxy with Tomcat 8.5 using http2

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, mod-proxy, http2

Is it possible to use `mod_proxy` in front of an Apache Tomcat 8.5 with the http2 protocol? If yes it would be nice to see an example configuration.

**Edit**

Specifically: Is it possible and recommended to use http2 between the client and the server (`Apache httpd`), and *continue* the data stream with `ajp` between `Apache httpd` and `Apache Tomcat`?

**Edit 2**

This answer provides some details about the topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697681/can-we-use-apache-to-deliver-http-2-connection-for-a-java-application-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache httpd added HTTP/2 proxy support from 2.4.21 but suggest you run latest (2.4.27 at time of writing) as this module is still changing quite a bit at the moment.

Tomcat has just added HTTP/2 support in Tomcat 9: https://readlearncode.com/configure-tomcat-9-for-http2/

So in theory this should all fit together nicely if you're willing to upgrade to those versions (and install OpenSSL 1.0.2 or above required for HTTP/2).

However, in practice it's still all very new, so bugs are possible. To be perfectly honest, the biggest gains from HTTP/2 are with higher-latency connections like client-to-server. Server-to-server connections like Apache to Tomcat using mod_proxy will see fewer gains.

So, given how new these are, you may wish to just use HTTP/2 on your Apache web server (or any other web server which supports HTTP/2), and use mod_proxy to connect to Tomcat via HTTP/1.1 or AJP. This will give you most of the performance gains of HTTP/2 without the hassle and risk of upgrading everything to get full end-to-end HTTP/2.

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2017, Apache `mod_proxy` doesn't support HTTP/2.0 protocol. There is a `mod_proxy_http2`[1](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http2.html) module but it is still experimental.

Like detailed in the StackOverflow answer provided in the second edit, you could use `mod_http2` to enable HTTP/2.0 support on Apache side, and communicate back to the Tomcat server either with HTTP/1.1 or AJP. But you would loose one of HTTP/2.0 biggest feature: multiplexing.